# Assigning a CString to a class's CString

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I have the following code that should assign a CString from main to the class CWav, however for some reason the CS_AuthFileName never gets assigned a name and stays empty.

main.cpp

```
        CWav Wav_player;
        CString m_strFileName = strFile;//strFile is the name of a file I am interested in that has already been set 

        CString AuthFile = m_strFileName;
        AuthFile.Truncate(AuthFile.GetLength() - 3);
        

        AuthFile.Append("auth");

        Wav_player.AuthFileName = AuthFile;
```

wav.cpp

```
class CWav{
public:
CString CS_AuthFileName;
};
```

Comment: This looks correct. The error is probably in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: You show the assignment of `AuthFileName` in the code at the top and then a `CS_AuthFileName` member in the code underneath. Obviously that isn't your real code. Chances are your problem is in your real code but won't be found if you edit it too much to post out here.